# NgControl on Custom Directive in Angular2

Tags: angular, web-component, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-forms

I am trying to use ngControl on Custom Component. I have created the component and implemented `ControlValueAccessor` on the component.

Then in the constructor, NgControl is injected as below:

```
constructor(@Self() private ngControl: NgControl){
   this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
}
```

But this way when i use the ngControl on the selector, the form classes (`ng-pristine , ng-touched, ng-invalid`) are not updated, nor can i check the value of the form element.

Can anyone help out where i am doing it wrong.

---

Adding to the description of the problem
I tried to [Thierry Templier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1873365/thierry-templier) solution, with the limited knowledge in angular2 but I get into a circular reference error.

Detailing more in the issue, I Have a component `MyComponent` which I am using in a `ContainerComponent`, when i use `ngControl` in container component, with the changes described by Thierry Templier, made to `MyComponent`, I get the circular reference error, something like: (`MyComponent -> ngControl ..... -> token** -> MyComponent`).

Any suggestions around that.

Comment: Please post a demo of your component.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you need to register your value accessor into the providers of your component. Note that it can be itself: the component is the value accessor and needs to be registered itself in its providers). In fact this case `forwardRef` is helpful.

Something like that:

```
const CUSTOM_VALUE_ACCESSOR = new Provider(
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {useExisting: forwardRef(() => LabelsValueAccessor), multi: true});

@Component({
  (...)
  providers: [CUSTOM_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class LabelsValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
  (...)
}
```

Comment: I tried to use it, with the limited knowledge in angular2. I get into a circular reference error. Any suggestions around that.